# 賭博師と遊び人の違いはなんですか？

Tags: meaning

Playing a game and there are these two classes/jobs 賭博師 and 遊び人.  I do not quite understand the difference between them.  They seem to both mean gambler, but is there some difference? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

賭博師 simply refers to a serious, professional gambler.

Dictionaries seem to say one of the meanings of 遊び人 is gambler, but this word is almost never used in this sense today. As the kanji suggests, in real life, this word usually refers to an unemployed person, a debauchee, a playboy, etc.

In addition, in gaming contexts, 遊び人 is best-known as a job in *Dragon Quest* franchise. This job name is translated as [Gadabout or Jester](https://dragon-quest.org/wiki/Gadabout). Dragon Quest has been so popular in Japan that virtually all Japanese game developers know this character stereotype. If your game was made by Japanese people, an 遊び人 may look like this. For example, the [article about 遊び人 on ピクシブ百科事典](https://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E9%81%8A%E3%81%B3%E4%BA%BA) is almost entirely about Dragon Quest's 遊び人.

Answer (score 3):

賭博師{とばくし} always implies their profession is related to gambling such as playing poker, betting on horse racing, roulette, casino, and so on. I am not so sure a profession like "[bookmaker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmaker)", who mainly sets up gambling opportunists, can be called 賭博師{とばくし}, who is actually betting on something and taking a lot of risk.

遊{あそ}び人{にん} implies someone is spending a prodigal life. One of their activities might be gambling but it is not their main profession and they are getting used to other leisure activities.